# Best way to create a relationship between custom taxonomy and post for custom sorting in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom taxonomy for wordpress. I would like to have the ability to have a draggable list to sort the order the posts appear in. So it would be like a series of posts where you would have the ability to sort which posts appear first on down the list.

Right now I am doing this with custom meta on both the post and the taxonomy. So I have a series list in an array in the taxonomy by just adding something

```
function add_series_order_meta_field_when_created( $term_id ) {
  add_term_meta($term_id, 'series_order', array(), true);
}
add_action( 'create_series_post', 'add_series_order_meta_field_when_created');
```

Then when a post is saved I am checking if the post id is in the series order array and if not I am adding it. Then I am also checking if the taxonomy id was removed from the post ect.

```
// automatically add post_ID to the series_order meta 
function add_series_order_on_save($post_ID, $post) {
  if($post->post_status !== 'publish') return;
  
  $selected_series_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_ID, 'series_post');
  $prev_series_term_ids = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'prev_series_term_ids', true);
  $new_series_term_ids = array();
  
  if(!empty($selected_series_terms)) {
    foreach($selected_series_terms as $term) {
      $series_order = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'series_order', true);
      array_push($new_series_term_ids, $term->term_id);

      if(!in_array($post_ID, $series_order)){
        array_push($series_order, $post_ID);
        update_term_meta($term->term_id, 'series_order', $series_order);
      }
    }
  }

  if(!empty($prev_series_term_ids)) {
    foreach($prev_series_term_ids as $term_id) {
      
      if(!in_array($term_id, $new_series_term_ids)) {
        $series_order = get_term_meta($term_id, 'series_order', true);
        $idx = array_search($post_ID, $series_order);

        if($idx !== false) {
          array_splice($series_order, $idx, 1);
          update_term_meta($term_id, 'series_order', $series_order);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  update_post_meta($post_ID, 'prev_series_term_ids', $new_series_term_ids);
}
add_action('wp_after_insert_post', 'add_series_order_on_save', 10, 2);
```

My problem with this is that when listing the posts in the series I feel like I would have to just loop through the series list and make a query to the database for every post in the series. I thought about just adding a series order spot meta to the post itself but each post could be part of several different series. Also when doing that when I go to change the desired order of the series I would have to loop through and change the order number of each post in the series.

So what would be the best way to make a relationship between the posts order in the series and the custom taxonomy so I can make one query to the database to be able to sort the posts in the taxonomy in the custom order that is set by the draggable list?

Hopefully I explained that well. If not let me know in the comments for clarification.

Comment: Where are you sorting these on the front end or admin?

Comment: @HowardE Both the front and admin. Although not sure why that matters. I more need help with what is the best way to set up the relationship. I think I may have just settled on putting the series order index in the post meta.

Comment: You can use `menu_order` which wouldn't require a meta_query